# Fast database for a small microcontroller

Tags: database-recommendation, embedded

I am using a PIC32, which is a 32-bit processor clocked at 80 MIPS with about 64-128KB of RAM available. It will be accessing a microSD card - up to 4 GB, on a FAT32 filesystem. Running all of this is pushing it, but I need a compact database that can be easily ported to this platform and one which is fast. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Although I fail to see usefulness for this, I'm very curious about that.

Comment: Which OS is it running on?

Comment: @IanC... uh... not really running an OS, just a single program.

Comment: @IanC, If any OS, it could be something like FreeRTOS.

Comment: Do you want a relational/SQL DB or something different like a key-value store?

Answer (score 6):

A ported version of SQL Lite is probably your best bet. See [this](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m469667.aspx) thread.